# The type initializer for '[Modulename]' threw an exception

Tags: vb.net, exception, module

I have this new vb.net project (MedicalCost) having this error "The type initializer for 'MedicalCost.Constants' threw an exception." when running the sub.. I've already done this before on my previous project and everything works fine when I'm declaring ang public varible on my module but now in my current project its not working.

here is my code on my module(Constants):

```
 Imports System.Data.Sql
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.Data.Odbc
    Imports System.Windows.Forms

    Public Module Constants
        Public ppiconn As New SqlConnection("Dsn=pandiman2002connectdsn;server=ppi;uid=sa;database=Pandimandata2002")
        'Dsn=pandiman2002connectdsn;description=PPI Database;uid=sa;app=Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2010;wsid=CRWUSER17-PC;database=Pandimandata2002
        Public da As New SqlDataAdapter
        Public comm As New SqlCommand
        Public dr As SqlDataReader
        Public ds As New DataSet

        Public x As String


    End Module
```

when im running the sub on my frm_add

here is my code

```
Sub search_crew()

    Try
        x = "(isnull(ltrim(rtrim(firstname)),'') + ' ' + isnull(ltrim(rtrim(mi)),'') + ' ' + " _
               & "isnull(ltrim(rtrim(lastname)),'') like '%" & Replace(searchbox.Text, " ", "%") & "%' " _
               & " or isnull(ltrim(rtrim(lastname)),'') + ' ' + isnull(ltrim(rtrim(mi)),'') + ' ' + " _
               & "isnull(ltrim(rtrim(firstname)),'') like '%" & Replace(searchbox.Text, " ", "%") & "%' " _
               & "or legal_records.caseno like '%" & UCase(searchbox.Text) & "%')"

        ppiconn.Close()
        ppiconn.Open()
        Pandimandata2002DataSet.EnforceConstraints = False
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(select_tblcrw & "where " & x, ppiconn)
        da.Fill(Pandimandata2002DataSet.tblCrew)
        da.Dispose()
        ppiconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I noticed that any variable declared from module is the reason why this error "The type initializer for 'MedicalCost.Constants' threw an exception." occurs.

can anyone help me. I already spent 1 hour searching for this error and nothings helps me.
tnx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly the following line of code

```
Public ppiconn As New SqlConnection("Dsn=pandiman2002connectdsn;server=ppi;uid=sa;database=Pandimandata2002")
```

The key here is `type initializer` in the error message.  That happens when the initialization of static data throws an exception.  For VB.Net this maps to the fields of `Modules` or `Shared` fields of `Class`.  In this case the error points to `Constants` and this is the only initializer hence it is likely to blame.

In order to find out why this happens you will need to find the exception which triggered the `type initializer` error.  Simply debug into the application wait for the error, expand the `InnerException` property and that should contain the real error

Comment: THANKS!!! I got it! the found that the real error in "{"Keyword not supported: 'dsn'."}" I remove it on my connection and it works! thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem with Initializer in a module for Public definitions -- Moved the initializer To the Form using it -- Still as Public. The Problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

This error came up for me when I updated a reference to a 3rd-party DLL.  The error "The type initializer for {myForm} threw an exception" appeared on creating the main form in the installed program and the program halted with the splash screen visible.  The debugger was no help because the program ran correctly in the debugger.  It turned out that my installer was not including some of the updated 3rd-party dependencies for the DLL.  Once the updated dependencies were identified and added into the program folder by the installer, the program ran correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with this code:

```vb
Partial Class ProductProperties
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Shared GENERATING_MESSAGE As String = "Generating Report"
    Private Shared STEPS As Integer = 0
    Private Shared MAX_STEPS As Integer = 5

    Public Shared CurrentUserName As String
.
.
.
```

I then changed the declaration of `CurrentUserName` to include setting it to a value:

```
Public Shared CurrentUserName As String = " "
```

That fixed it for me.